# Azure services events collection

Tags: azure

I'm following this Azure guid :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/events/get-by-type#examples

And when I'm trying to use the sample requests : https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/DEMO_APP/events/traces

Instead of getting a valid response I get:
{"error":{"message":"Valid authentication was not provided","code":"AuthorizationRequiredError","correlationId":"f5bb5980-26fc-4afb-bfec-b41729a2a81b"}}

Any ideas how can I fix it?
(I logged in to my Azure account and after that I tried to use the request above)

Comment: I believe you need to add the auth token according to this link
https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization

Either in header or in query param

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [PK214](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14567766/pk214). Adding your comment as answer to help other community users.

> Add the auth token according to this link
> [dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization)
> Either in header or in query param